# Get exact minutes pine-script

Tags: pine-script

I am creating a script so that I can print the exact minute of the candle regardless of the UTC time that I choose, but everything is in unix time and it does not give me exactly the minute

How can I get the exact minute regardless of the temporality of the bar?

I already indicate minute, minute (time) but only as a result of the temporality of the bar and not in the exact minute of the market

```
if ((minute(time) >= 0.0 and minute(time) <= 4.0) or (minute(time) >= 30.0 and minute(time) <= 34.0))
    min := min + 1
else
    min := min * 0
```

The expected results are:
min = 0 or min = 1 or min = 2 or min = 3 or min = 4 or min = 30 or min = 31 or min = 32 or min = 33 or min = 34
Any of those results

Comment: So you want to plot time always in UTC, independent of the timezone chosen in the chart. Am I right?

Comment: Note that you cannot print any variables in pine-script.

Comment: @Baris Yakut I suppose he means to plot the values